# "Action" button seems to be oddly placed in Android app

Tags: discussion, status-completed, android-app

While using the Android app, I've attempted to click on this little action button multiple times to see what it does. I either can't click on it, or I manage to select the title which opens my browser to the question. But it doesn't seem like it's related to the title due to it's placement closer to the tags than the title.

Is there going to be a menu when you click on this? Or is the purpose to know that the title is clickable?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently that "action button" exists for comments to show that they are clickable and bring up the comment options menu. The same button was added to the title element to show that it's clickable and clicking it will open the page in the mobile website, but I agree with you that it's quite confusing to have that there.

I've taken out the icon for the next builds and we can see if there needs to be more than just the color of the title to show that it's clickable.

P.S. Thanks for the screenshot, I would've had no idea what you were mentioning without it.

Comment: I honestly didn't know what to call it... glad the screenshot did it's job! I could see that button opening a menu that would allow flagging, editing or sharing the question using the Android sharing system.

Comment: @StevenV Yeah, that's what we were planning on too, but since none of that is implemented yet taking the confusing element out seemed like the better choice.

Comment: @StevenV Just as a follow up, we ended up moving that to be a button on the timestamp. Let me know what you think :)

Comment: Looking forward to this release! Seems like you guys have been pretty busy!

Comment: I like the new position of the button. It seems to make more sense with the options that are available in the menu.