# Android options button is hard to distinguish

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, android-app

In the Android application the button which take us to the options of open in browser/favorite/flag/share/edit, is somewhat indistinguishable from the rest of the questions itself.

Should be made more clear?

Edit: If I'm complaining about clearness, I should be clearer too. Here is an image that shows off that button:

[image: Hard to see]

Comment: I'm looking at the app right now... what button are you talking about? (I guess it must be really hard to distinguish, because I don't see it. :) )

Comment: @Bart The little arrow that points downwards and to the right, which opens up a menu with those options in it. AFAIK the arrow is the only way to open that menu, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Oh wow .... you opened up a new world to me @animuson.

Comment: And that is exactly why I'm complaining. I'd add that I think the design is not less than wonderful, but it need, at least a little tutorial to figure out how it works. Thanks by enforcing my point @Bart

Comment: I think you have me to blame for it being moved to the timestamp... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192000/action-button-seems-to-be-oddly-placed-in-android-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of version 1.0.7 the indicator for that area looks like this:

[image]

The reason for its positioning is that we wanted to use the same click area for both questions and answers so when people learn it once they don't have to learn how to do it another way in a similar view. We originally had these options on the title area but since answers don't have titles it didn't make sense.

It seems like this new indicator is taking care of some of the confusion, we haven't seen many people request features that are already implemented but found in that dialog since the release, and we definitely saw that before 1.0.7.

Answer (score 1):

I agree it should be more clear.  While to me that arrow is obviously a button, I expected it to elaborate on "asked 2 hours ago".  To wit, I should expect it to show me the exact date and time (like mouseover does on the main site) and also the revision history (like clicking "edited 2 hours ago" would on the main site).

Using that as the flair to access Share and Flag is very non-intuitive.